# Java - How to assign a value to a variable during unit test different than a value at runtime

Tags: java, unit-testing, runtime

Let's say that I have a method which uses a `final static String` from another class such as a common class.

```
public class Common {
    public static final String MY_STRING = "This is my string";
    public static final String TEST_STRING = "This is a test time string";
}
```

`Common` class may be used by multiple classes. Here is a sample class that uses the `Common` class.

```
public class MyClass {

    private String variable = Common.MY_STRING;

    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println(variable);

        // some other codes
    }
}
```

Now, assume that I want `myMethod` to use `Common.TEST_STRING` during the unit test, but still use `Common.MY_STRING` at runtime. In other words, how can I manage `variable` in `MyClass` to be assigned with different values for test and runtime?

The most intuitive solution would be just to pass the string as a parameter to the method. But, I don't want to use this approach, as I only have a simplified case on this example.

Comment: you could use a parameter on your config or just a hardcoded static final boolean that tells if the code is for testing or production

Comment: You could take in the `String` in a constructor.  You could have a `setMyString` method in `Common`.  You could Reflectively change it.  You could make a `getter` method for the `myString` and then mock that.  There's a lot of different options depending on what makes the most sense to you and your project.

Comment: having a `getter` and mocking seems to be a good fit for my case. Thanks

Comment: *"having a getter and mocking seems to be a good fit for my case."* - I discourage from doing so for two reasons: **1:** getters/setters expose internal details of your class and therefore break the *encapsulation/information hiding* paradigm. **2:**  You should avoid code in your production that exists only for testing.  --- I'd suggest the constructor parameter approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below,

//Function Definition

```
public void setDrivers(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName, Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException{
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiers.setAccessible(true);
    modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, value);
}
```